# Iterate +1 over array two indices two at a time

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

In Ruby, given this array

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

how do i produce

```
> 0, 1
> 1, 2
> 2, 3
> 3, 4
> 4, 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].each_cons(2){|a| puts a.join(", ")}
```

Answer (score 3):

`each_cons` for sure, but another way:

```
enum = [0,1,2,3,4,5].to_enum
loop do
  puts "#{enum.next}, #{enum.peek}"
end
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
```

See [Kernel#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) and [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). Note the docs for all `Kernel` instance methods are shown at [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html), whereas `Kernel` module methods are documented at [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html).

Comment: `Array.send(:method, :to_enum).owner #=> Kernel`, but the doc for `:to_enum` is nowhere to be found at [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html). Help!

Comment: Usual `Kernel` methods are listed under `Object`. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum. That is sort of misleading indeed.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. To be more precise, "`Kernel` *instance methods* are listed under `Object`". [ref: second sentence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html).